# ALL time groovy compilation error

Tags: groovy

All time am getting below error message in groovy...

Could not understand whats causing this " Unexpected token error" ????

I used to think only PERL give bad compilation error,now groovy outperforming it..

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
D:\Playground\groovy\release-b-work\cmd_line_soapui\trial.groovy: 12: 
unexpected token: myrunner @ line 12, column 1.    
myrunner.setProjectFile("D:\soapui-release-B\try.xml");
      ^
  1 error
```

Code taken from comment;

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIProTestCaseRunner;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.*;
class trial {
  def myrunner = new com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIProTestCaseRunner();
  myrunner.setProjectFile("D:\soapui-release-B\try.xml");
  myrunner.setTestSuite("MediaAssetServiceTestSuite");
  myrunner.setTestCase("createMediaAsset TestCase");
  myrunner.run();
}
```

Comment: With out your code we can't help you figure out what the error is.

Comment: Hmm..  How to add code Tag here ?

Comment: I pasted the code from your comment into your question (which you should be able to edit yorself)...  Doesn't seem to be the code that's causing the error though...

Comment: thanks tim.. however.. I get error .. "unexpected Token"

Comment: That's the code you posted in a comment, not a suggestion for a fix.  The code you supplied is not where the error is...  THe error is in `soapui.em3.releb.propUpdate`.  Not sure if that's a class...  Do you not use capitalization for class names?

Comment: In `soapui.em3.releb.propUpdate` on line `17`, the compiler hit the word `Logger` when it wasn't expecting to.  Without seeing the code, I'd guess you have either 1) Not closed a brace properly `{`, `[` or `(` 2) Not closed a String delimiter properly `'` or `"`

Comment: I checked all these basics of ( { [ ' " stuff.. nothing is wrong in the code..any other clue ?

Comment: Paste the code into the question? (like you have been asked by both @Jared and myself?)

Comment: tim..code pasted by you is the code.. refresh it once more. please

Comment: Ahh, I see...now you have posted the real error, it's easier to see what's wrong...

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use an IDE with Groovy support. Idea has it out of the box, Eclipse has it with http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code in a method

You can't just add code into a class at class level

Try:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIProTestCaseRunner;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*;
import com.eviware.soapui.*;

class trial {
  def someMethod() {
    def myrunner = new com.eviware.soapui.SoapUIProTestCaseRunner();
    myrunner.setProjectFile("D:\soapui-release-B\try.xml");
    myrunner.setTestSuite("MediaAssetServiceTestSuite");
    myrunner.setTestCase("createMediaAsset TestCase");
    myrunner.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I got another groovy error now ..Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: This script or class could not be run.
It should either:
- have a main method,
- be a JUnit test, TestNG test or extend GroovyTestCase,
- or implement the Runnable interface.